# Make the largest number of the number

Tags: c#, arrays, stringbuilder

i try to make the largest number, of entered number. Have some ideas, but all of them end by error.

```
int n = 123 // in the end shell be 321, 567 -> 765, 184 -> 841
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(n.ToString());
            int[] aray = new int[3];
            for (int i = 0;i < str.Length;i++) {
                aray[i] = int.Parse(str[i].ToString());
            }
            aray.OrderBy(x => x);
            var a = aray.Join(' '); //eror
            Console.WriteLine(a);
```

Comment: Use `String.Join`

Comment: What you want is `string.Join(aray, " ")`, but notice that the `OrderBy` is being discarded (not executed)

Comment: Just convert it to string sort it in reverse order done!

Comment: @JaysmitoMukherjee How does that work with `184`?

Comment: Something like `new string(Arrays.Reverse(String.Concat("123".OrderBy(c => c)).ToCharArray()))` may work

Comment: `string result = string.Concat(n.ToString().OrderByDescending(c => c));`

Comment: Sorry was miss click, it should have been 184 -> 841

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of code to accomplish something very simple:

```
var ans = int.Parse(String.Concat(n.ToString().OrderByDescending(dc => dc)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, we have two cases: *postive* and *negative* numbers:

```
n =  43125 ->  54321
n = -43125 -> -12345
```

We can hold both cases with a help of *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq:

...

string result = string.Concat(n < 0  
  ? n.ToString().OrderBy(c => c)
  : n.ToString().OrderByDescending(c => c));
```

Here we exploit the fact that `'-' < '0'` and we don't have to do any special work for `-` in case of negative numbers. If you want to obtain `int` value, just add `int.Parse`:

```
int result = int.Parse(string.Concat(n < 0  
  ? n.ToString().OrderBy(c => c)
  : n.ToString().OrderByDescending(c => c)));
```

but be *careful*: large `n` will cause *integer overflow*:

```
n = 1234567890 -> 9876543210 > int.MaxValue
```

Comment: Very nice answer.